# Getting Error from webpack-cli: "TypeError: merge is not a function" in webpack config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-cli, webpack-merge

I'm using webpack-merge to combine two webpack.config files together but I keep getting the error
"TypeError: merge is not a function when I run the command "webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.prod.js"

Has anybody else run across this issue?

webpack.config.prod.js

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const commonConfig= require('./webpack.config.common');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {

    //config code
 
})
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You are importing `merge` incorrectly. Try it like this:

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
```

**UPD:**
Based on the [following changelog](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge/blob/50bf401c7f2d205721e8cfa9a03ea47cf80058ec/CHANGELOG.md#503--2020-07-06), starting with `webpack-merge` 5.0.3 and higher, you should use the code I provided above. If the version is lower than 5.0.3, then you need to use:

```js
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
```

Comment: that fixed it 
I was confused because I have another project that has it written the other way and it works fine 
I'll assume it's a version issue

Comment: Yes, it is a version issue as it is working without the curly brackets in Webpack v^4.2.2 but not in v^5.1.1

Comment: not working `"webpack": "^5.3.2", "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2" `

Comment: Based on the [following changelog](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge/blob/50bf401c7f2d205721e8cfa9a03ea47cf80058ec/CHANGELOG.md#503--2020-07-06), starting with `webpack-merge` 5.0.3 and higher, you should use the code that I gave in the solution. If the version is lower than 5.0.3, then you need to use `const merge = require('webpack-merge');`.

Comment: Breaking changes like this are part of why Javascript development can be incredibly frustrating. (Thanks, btw!)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do this using cmd.

```
webpack -m -c ./webpack.config.js -c ./webpack.dev.js
```

or you can create a script in package.json for faster use

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack -m -c ./webpack.config.js -c 
    ./webpack.dev.js",
  },
```