# Getting error from webpack-cli : TypeError: merge.smart is not a function

Tags: webpack

I have an error when I do `yarn build`, i get this error :

```
TypeError: merge.smart is not a function
     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/config/webpack.prod.js:9:24)
     at Module._compile (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
     at require (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
     at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:114:13)
     at requireConfig (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:6)
     at /var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
     at module.exports (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
     at /var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
     at Object.parse (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
     at /var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Dragons/PROJETPERSO/PORTFOLIO/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Does anyone have any idea to remedy my problem?

PS : my webpack version is 4.44.2

Comment: is this duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846123/getting-error-from-webpack-cli-typeerror-merge-is-not-a-function-in-webpack

Comment: Nope.. its a different issue. In that question, they cover how to correctly import webpack-merge. However, you will get this error even if your import is fine, since they removed smart from version 5 onwards of webpack-merge.

Answer (score -1):

Try to down the version to 4.2.1